# Windows process management tools

Tags: windows, unix, process, upstart

Unix has tools like upstart, angel, god, etc to keep processes running constantly on system start and can restart processes that have failed. Does windows have the ability to do this natively?

Comment: The above "red tape" stated...the built-in service manager can be set to restart services that fail to start or stop, and other tools like SCOM and others can monitor services and processes and have mitigation policies to either restart the service/process or notify a sysadmin, etc.

Comment: @TheCleaner thank you for the service manager info.
http://tools.sysprogs.org/srvman/

Comment: That's 3rd party...the built in services.msc is what I was referring to.  But my first comment is because SF simply doesn't allow "point me to some software tools/choices" anymore like it used to back in the day.  Look at the first "Related" question on the right side here as an example.  That's not to say you won't get comments or valid answers, just that it is most likely to still be closed as you have asked it.  Perhaps change your last sentence to "How can I make sure a Windows process can have the same "features"?" instead of asking for a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom service in Windows using `sc` .  For relevant setup information, enter `sc create /?` in a command prompt.

After service creation, you can use the Services applet to configure parameters using a GUI if you prefer that.  Run `services.msc` to open the applet.  You can define parameters for service start on boot, restart actions, services account for the executable to run under, etc.